# python program output with trailing zero.. How to get output with zero

Tags: python-3.x

```py
import math

def GeoSum(k):
    if (k == 0):
        return 1

    return GeoSum(k - 1) + 1 / math.pow(2,k)


k = int(input())
ans = (GeoSum(k))
print(ans)
```

*Example:* at `n=4` output is 1.9375
but how to get the output as 1.93750

Comment: Do you want a trailing zero, or 5 digits after the decimal point? What is ``n``?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module which is very useful for increasing the precision of a floating-point number.

```
import math
import decimal
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 5 #Since you want the 5 level of precision

def GeoSum(k):
    if (k == 0):
        return 1

    return GeoSum(k - 1) + 1 / Decimal(math.pow(2,k))


k = int(input())
ans = (GeoSum(k))
#If you want to print the trailing zeros as well. Then do as following 
print('{:.5f}'.format(ans))
```

Note: Kindly note that for the `input 4` you have the maximum precision of `1.9375`. If you give some other inputs you will see the increase in precision.

If you want the trailing zeros in the output to be kept check this link [trailing zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238120/keep-trailing-zeroes-in-python).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: This does not output a trailing zero. Also, please be aware that comments in Python start with ``#``, not ``//``. ``//`` is the floor division operator.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for the suggestion. I have added that part as well. I have added some more details to him. Anyways thanks for pointing out that part and kindly unvote the answer if you have given the downvote for that reason since the answer is useful for him now. Thank you once again.

Comment: The new, relevant part is [a link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Please include the relevant information *in you answer*.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Kindly check it now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot..i learned something new @Saurav Rai

Comment: Thank u @Saurav Rai  for helping me out.

Comment: @PraveenLohar I am glad that it helped you. Kindly accept the answer as well for the benefit of future users also. Thanks.