# How to keep arbitrary number of trailing 0s in float?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to keep track of the number of significant digits in a number (float or integer). Trailing zeroes after a decimal point are considered significant, e.g. in 12.0 there are 3 significant figures and in 12.00 there are 4. I thought to use something like `len(str(number))` but this removes all but one of the trailing zeroes from floats. The `format()` function and `str.format()` method, often suggested for similar questions ([in integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8593355/how-do-i-count-the-trailing-zeros-in-integer), [in float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15238120/keep-trailing-zeroes-in-python), and [float again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8568233/how-to-print-float-to-n-decimal-places-including-trailing-0s)) would both seemingly require me to know in advance how many decimal points I wanted. Is there a good way to go about this? Should I just require the number to be inputted as a string so that all trailing zeroes are preserved? The code I'm using to find significant figures is below. I believe that it works for all cases except that described above.

```
def __init__(self, value):
    """Initializes a Sigfig object with the given value and finds the number of significant figures in value"""
    assert type(value)==int or type(value)==float or type(value)==Sigfig, "Sigfig value must be of type int, float, or Sigfig" 
    # I wanted to avoid values of type str so that I don't have to worry about inputs like Sigfig('55b')
    self.value=value #This is to allow math with full value to avoid losing precision to rounding
    self.valuestring=f'{value}'
    #Remove leading zeroes before or after a decimal point and scientific notation
    self.remlead0enot=self.valuestring.lstrip('0').lstrip('.').lstrip('0').split('e',1)[0]
    #Account for ambiguous zeroes before implied decimal point e.g. 1000
    if '.' not in self.valuestring and self.valuestring[-1]=='0':
        self.sigfigs=len(self.remlead0enot.rstrip('0'))
    #Account for floats e.g. 1.005 and ints e.g. 105
    else:
        self.sigfigs=len(self.remlead0enot)-1 if '.' in self.remlead0enot else len(self.remlead0enot)
```

Comment: You can't really do arbitrary float to significant digit conversion meaningfully, since all digits of a float is technically significant. I would suggest your data structure to keep track of significant digits separately

Comment: The number of trailing zeroes is a string property, not a numeric one.  Once you've converted to `float` that information is lost forever.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting significant figures in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8101353/counting-significant-figures-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve but if if your question is if you can make a float remember with how many trailing zeros it was stored with: No.

You can only define how many points after the comma should be included when you convert the float to a string. But the float itself has no concept about significant digits. (Aka: `3.000000f == 3.0f`)

If you need to know the amount of trailing zeros, yes, you need the input to be a string.
When you already have a string though you can also just store how many numbers are after the `.`.

```
arg_as_str = "3.100"
decimal_points = len(arg.split(".")[1]) # 3
as_float = float(arg) # 3.1
...
output_as_str = f"{as_float:{decimal_points}f}" # "3.100"
```

Hope that was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into the package `mpmath`. This package is made specifically for this purpose, to allow arbitrary precision of floats.

https://mpmath.org/

Comment: From my brief look, it looks like this package allows arbitrary but, importantly, pre-defined precision. Keeping track of significant figures (based on a number, not user input) requires being able to choose different amounts of precision for different numbers. Please let me know if I missed something important in the package, though.